# SearchViewにタッチせずに補完候補を出せない

Tags: android

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview);
searchView.requestFocus();
```

などでフォーカスは当てられます。SearchViewを継承して以下のコードでタッチしてフォーカスを当てたら０文字で補完候補が出るようにはなっています。

```
SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchAutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
searchAutoComplete.setThreshold(-1);
```

ですが、一度もタッチをせずに候補を出すにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
}
```

Windowサイズが確定していないとダメなようでした。上記のコードで解決しました。